# How to speed up for entering data in textbox in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a textbox in silverlight object. This textbox is used for storing characters. When user types text in this textbox, it woks fine till 2000 characters, but after that its speed decreses. And i dont want this. This textbox will be used for storing max characters. There is no limitation for entering text in it.

So what should i do that it will be fluid and its speed will be same as before.

Comment: Are yo using any bindings with this textbox?

Comment: Yes. i am using two bindings. First for 'Text' property binding and another is 'KeyUp' EventTrigger. I also thought this. 
So for this, i used a simple textbox without any binding in xaml page. But all is vain, Speed of entering text decreses as keypress increses for this textbox also, as there is no binding.